# How do I sync the time for my linux guest VM through VMware Fusion?

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, vmware-fusion

I have Ubuntu server 9.10 running through VMware Fusion 2.0.6 on my Mac OSX 10.5 host.  My linux guest VM's time keep being out of sync.  I believe I have VMware tools installed because after running the following on linux in the terminal, I get:

```
$vmware-toolbox-cmd timesync status
Enabled
```

What should I do to make sure my time is always in sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current [recommendation by VMware](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006427) is to run NTP on the guest.